# History of Dead Locks

Tags: sql-server

How can we get the information on the past history of dead locks.For example today at 10 AM. 
Thank you

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: I would start here: [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

I stand corrected by @Martin Smith.  Refer to his link on how to use SQL Server Extended Events to look query out historical deadlock graphs.  Looks like this was added in SQL 2008.  Learn something every day.

Original:

SQL Server does not have a provision for looking at past deadlocks.  You must be running an active trace that has the appropriate trace flags set.  The link that Robert Harvey [listed above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx) is a great place to start.  You can also use [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx) and specify the Locks->Deadlock Graph event type and ensure the `TextData` column is specified to get another view of the deadlock graph.  I personally find using the Profiler trace to be easier.

Comment: [SQL Server 2008 does](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/deadlock-error-isnt-returning-the-deadlock-sql/10646#10646)